# rmarkdown::render Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) for 'params' objects when 'intermediates_dir' option set to anything except 'NULL'

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I am trying to parameterize the rendering of chunks of an rmarkdown document.

To do this, I set the knitr chunk option `eval` to a parameter defined in the yaml header and can be passed as an option via `rmarkdown::render`'s `params` option.

Let's say the following is my rmarkdown document called `mydocument.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "mydocument"
params: 
  query: TRUE
---

```{r}
query <- params$query
```

```{r eval=query}
cat('Hello world\n') 
```
````

The rendering of this document works fine when I use

```
rmarkdown::render(input = 'mydocument.Rmd', 
                 params = list(query = TRUE))
```

but when I use

```
rmarkdown::render(input = 'mydocument.Rmd', 
                 params = list(query = TRUE),
                 intermediates_dir = getwd())
```

The rendering still works, and I get the expected html output but I get the error message:

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'query' not found`

If `mydocument.Rmd` looked like this:

````
---
title: "mydocument"
params: 
  query: TRUE
---

```{r eval=params$query}
cat('Hello world\n') 
```
````

I get the error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'params' not found
```

Somehow changing the default value of intermediates_dir option causes this problem. I tried all other options of the `rmarkdown::render` function, but none of them show this behaviour.

I am not sure if this problem is a problem of rmarkdown, knitr, or pandoc.

#### Session Information

R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] rmarkdown_1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_1.5    formatR_1.4     htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.1     yaml_2.1.13     Rcpp_0.12.7
 [7] stringi_1.1.1   knitr_1.14      stringr_1.1.0   digest_0.6.10   evaluate_0.9

Comment: To me it does not raise any error.
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.1  backports_1.1.2 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.5.1     yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_0.12.18    stringi_1.1.7  
[10] rmarkdown_1.10  knitr_1.20      stringr_1.3.1   digest_0.6.15   evaluate_0.11